# How to write a date | date:"MM" inside an ng-class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I want to add the class `month` when `agent.createdAt | date:"MM"` equals to `todaymonth` (the  code is inside a directive):

```
'<td ng-class="{\'month\': ???==todaymonth}"><span>{{todaymonth}}</span>{{agent.createdAt | date:\"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm\"}}</td>'+
```

I don't know how to add the `agent.createdAt | date:"MM"`. If I do this:

`{\'month\': agent.createdAt | date:\"MM\"==todaymonth}` Throws an unexpected expression error same with `{\'month\': (agent.createdAt | date:\"MM\")==todaymonth}`

How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are putting in an expression, just use `class` instead of `ng-class`:

```
<td class="{{(createdAt | date:'MMM') == todayMonth ? (createdAt | date:'MMM') : ''}}">...</td>
```

The code above will give your `<td>` a class of *Jan*, *Feb*, etc., depending on the  month.

I had some issues with class names being numbers, so I used `MMM` instead. `todayMonth` needs to be something like `"Jan"` accordingly.

This [JSFiddle](//jsfiddle.net/8w0j60jb/) shows the whole thing in action.

**Note:** I changed some of the attribute names for better readability, so just copy & pasting into your code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've used getMonth() method of Date class which has an start index of 0 so I've added 1 in the expression

```
'<td ng-class="{ month: agent.createdAt.getMonth()+1==todaymonth}"><span>{{todaymonth}}</span>{{agent.createdAt | date:\"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm\"}}</td>'+
```

Comment: For some reason Angular returns nothing if I do `agent.createdAt.getMonth()` Maybe `getMonth()` is forbidden in Angular templates?

Comment: Is your createdAt a Date object?

Comment: Yes, it's a JavaScript's Date object. `{"objectId":"564aa46260b294bc1277cc25","username":"+886911111111","realname":"John Ian","emailVerified":false,"createdAt":"2015-11-17T03:52:02.707Z","reports":`

Comment: Oh, no. I think it's a string.